# Reason for the output of the following code :

Tags: c

I have a few lines of code for which I could't understand the reason for this output..

```
int main()
{
int a=5;
float b=10.5,c=11.0;
printf("%d",b);
printf("\n%d",c);
printf("\n%f",a);
return 0; 
}
```

O/p in Visual C++ :- 0 ,0 ,0.000000

gcc compiler :- 0,0, 11.000000

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you call a variadic function like `printf`, `float`s undergo promotion to `double`. `int`s are passed as-is. `printf` therefore expects a `double` when you write `%f`, and an `int` when you write `%d`.

Not giving it a `double`, but an `int`, is therefore **undefined behaviour**. Similarly, passing a `double` when the function expects an `int` is also undefined.

As usual, undefined behaviour means "anything could happen". Never, ever rely on undefined behaviour.

Comment: Excellent explanation, Thanks Wouldn't have got a better explantion than this one.. :)

Answer (score 4):

You are playing with undefined or unspecified behavior.  Not sure which one of them it is.  On my Debian with gcc 4.7.2, I get -780714744, 4195886, 11.000000 on the output.

Comment: +1, All of them are undefined. (a) sending a float to a format spec expecting an int, (b) same as (a), and finally (c) sending an `int` to a `float`-expecting spec-string. They're *all* wrong and UB.